# Where is it taught that you can't sleep with socks

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, clothing, rambam, sleep

I remember hearing that you can't sleep with socks. I think Rambam stated this (correct me if i am wrong), but where in Rambam was it said and why do we do it?

Comment: http://www.dinonline.org/2011/09/01/covering-feet-at-night/

Comment: @Danno The [Mishna Berura](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.2) cited there is an answer -- why don't you post one?

Comment: @Shokhet this is interesting info but not an answer until it can be ascertained that the motivation for the question was tznius and not health or superstition.

Comment: @user6591 I think it's just a source for the idea of caring whether or not someone sleeps in socks. The Rambam is not a place you'd generally find superstitions, IMO.

Comment: but mainly why do we do it

Comment: @user6591 See latest edit; that should answer your question.

Comment: @Shokhet just offering options for other reasons. Not advocating what makes sense or who would say what.

Comment: This lists many rules concerning sleep  https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Halachot_of_Sleep  but not specifically socks. I am rather certain I have heard discussions about sleeping with or without socks but I can’t find the source at the moment

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.68b.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en Be like Shlomo Hamelech.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a supplement to Matt's [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48803/5323); see [Mishna Berura 2:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.2), who writes that

> **מיושב:** דאז בהכרח יתגלה גופו והאדם צריך להתנהג בצניעות ובושה לפני הקב"ה ואפילו כשהוא לילה ובחדרי חדרים הלא מלא כל הארץ כבודו וכחשיכה
>   וכאורה לפניו יתברך....ע"כ **האנפלאות יראה ללבשם או לפשטם ג"כ תחת
>   הסדין** שלא לגלות רגליו שדרכן להיות מכוסות לעולם במדינות אלו שאין
>   הולכין יחף אפילו בקיץ....‏
>
> That way, a person would reveal his flesh, and a person needs to act
>   modestly wherever he is, even in private, because Hashem is
>   everywhere. Even at night, and in a closed room; for "the world is
>   filled with His glory," ([Yeshayahu 6:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15937#v=3)) and dark and light are the
>   same to Him....therefore, it would appear that **one should put on and
>   take off one's sock under his covers**, so that his feet should not be
>   uncovered, for it is the norm in our places to always walk around with
>   our feet covered, even in the summer we never walk barefoot....

( *my own translation* )

In context, it's clear that the issue with this is because of *tzniyus*, modest dressing.

[h/t Danno in comments]

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question (or why it has a checkmark). This cites a source for not going barefoot out of bed; the asker seeks a source for going barefoot in bed.

Comment: Although the OP selected this answer, it does not appear to answer the question as asked.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that this is only according to local custom and is not general halacha. This relates to a recent question concerning whether it is permissible or even preferable to pray without shoes on one’s feet. Think of removing ones shoes because the place on which you stand is holy. What if you are not standing, as in lying down?

Answer (score 16):

The Gemara (Yoma 78b) writes that one who sleeps with *shoes* on, 'has tasted a taste of death', and since tasting death is probably not a good thing, some poskim write that sleeping with shoes on should be avoided (see Kaf Hahayyim Y.D 116:211, for example). The book Shemiras Haguf Vehanefesh (no. 115) also writes that wearing shoes to sleep causes someone to forget his learning. However, this rule is never quoted by the Rambam (as far as I'm aware)

Perhaps some people believe that socks are like shoes in this regard, though I personally don't see why that would be the case. The Mishna Berurah 128:18 writes that while Kohanim are not allowed to wear shoes while they bless the congregation, they may (and should) do so while wearing socks - so at least in some respects socks and shoes are not equivalent

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because of this (but this is only for men)

Shulchan Aruch Harav [619.18](https://www.chabad.org/3385317/#v18) (from the Shalo)

> ...In addition, one should make a point of not covering himself with [so many] blankets and spreads that [his body] will be excessively warmed. One should at least leave his legs uncovered, as alluded to by the [uncovering of Boaz’ legs](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth.3.7?lang=bi), so that one’s body will not become excessively warmed.

Comment: See my answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94951/sleeping-with-feet-uncovered-for-unmarried-men/

Answer (score 1):

Additional [sources](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2187) regarding shoes, sandals and slippers (but not socks) include:

- Rav Yosef Haim of Baghdad, in Parashat Pinhas Shana Sheniya, 16
- Rav Haim Kanievsk

There is also a disagreement on the length of sleep required for this to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [Beis Yosef](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.317.3?lang=bi) brings that talmidei chachomim keep their shoes on the entire week. The Taz also brings this Sefer Haterumah.

> כתוב בס' התרומה ומורי מפרש מנעל של ת"ח שקושרים בחוזק רצועות מנעליהם
> ולומדים בלילות ואינם חולצים מנעליהם ולא פושטין לבושיהם כי אם משבת לשבת

Seemingly, the students did not mind the "Taste of Death". (see the answer of הנער הזה)