# Sleeping with feet uncovered for unmarried men

Tags: halacha, men-male, sleep

I was reading a book and the author mentioned as an example of someone being careful in Halacha that he "slept with his feet uncovered, as is the Halacha for unmarried men." I have never heard of this before. Is this a Halacha, a custom? Where can I find this?

Comment: off the top of my head I wonder if this is related to Boaz and Ruth -- he is sleeping and she uncovers his feet (3:4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is it taught that you can't sleep with socks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48800/where-is-it-taught-that-you-cant-sleep-with-socks)

Comment: see also http://dinonline.org/2011/09/01/covering-feet-at-night/ and https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/revealing-ones-feet/

Comment: @mbloch but he's specifying unmarried men

Comment: Do you know what book it was?

Comment: @Alex Samarkand. Pg 489

Comment: @mroll Thanks. Remember to edit any new information into the question post itself, rather than leaving it in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

While there is no requirement in halacha of sleeping with one's feet uncovered, nevertheless some men do so, with the belief that it can help prevent them from becoming aroused and having a nocturnal emission.

This idea is mentioned in the sefer "Sh'nei Luchot HaBrit" (Maseches Yoma, Amud HaTeshuva) in the context of preparation for sleep on Yom Kippur eve.

עוד דבר טוב הוא, בעת שהוא ישן בלילה, לא יעטף את עצמו בכרים ובכסתות המחממין כי זה מוליד כח התאוה, **ועל כל פנים לא יכסה את רגליו**. ודוגמא לזה תנן במסכת יומא (יט, ב) בכהן גדול שבקש להתנמנם, אומרים לו, אישי כהן גדול עמוד והפג אחת על הרצפה. והבאתי משנה זה לעיל במסכת שבועות, וכתבתי שזה היה טעם של רות ותגל מרגלותיו של בועז, כדי שלא יתחמם ויבוא לידי יצר:

Answer (score 2):

There is no such prohibition according to halacha and is permitted.

There is a discussion as to the extent of modesty in one's home to include removing socks under the sheets so that one remains covered even in privacy when undressing(see Mishna Brura 2:1). However, this is not m'ikar hadin, but a chassidut. Min hadin, it is permitted to sleep with or without socks.